# Como guardar en un nodo, con diferente llave, firebase?

Tags: firebase

Buen día, actualmente tengo estructurado el siguiente nodo principal `tarjetas`: Su contexto es que guardara las tarjetas que un usuario puedo tener
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En dicho nodo principal `tarjetas` se guardar como llave del objeto el `uid`, dicho objeto contendrá como propiedad otro objeto llamado `tarjetas` en dicho objeto se deben ir guardando las tarjetas que pertenezcan al usuario, básicamente quedando de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el nodo inferior "tarjetas" contendra n codigos.

Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
crearTarjeta(tarjeta){
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        let cod_tarjeta= tarjeta.numero_tarjeta.substr(-4);
        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("tarjetas")
          .child(uid+"/tarjetas")
          .set(cod_tarjeta)
          .then(()=>{
            console.log("AGREGANDO TARJETA");
          });
      }
    }
```

pero únicamente consigo que me quede de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muy agradecido, bendiciones.

Comment: Hola @JG_GJ , si te sirvio la respuesta podrias marcarla como correcta? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estas seteando el valor a tarjetas, deberias ir un nodo mas abajo

```
 firebase
          .database()
          .ref("tarjetas")
          .child(uid+"/tarjetas/"+cod_tarjeta)
          .set("Codigo de autorizacion")
          .then(()=>{
            console.log("AGREGANDO TARJETA");
          });
```

Esto deberia tener esta estructura:

```
 uid _ 
      |_tarjetas 
               |_ codigo de tarjeta : "codigo de autorizacion"
```